# Error implementando paginacion en LINQ .Net-Core Oracle 11g

Tags: linq, oracle-11g, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Estoy migrando unos repositorios de un webService hecho con C# .Net-Core. Desde SQLServer a Oracle

Este es el código que obtiene los resultados paginados.

```
public ModelPageable<Tercer> GetAll(QueryParameters queryParams)
    {
        IQueryable<Tercer> _allItems = _dbSet.OrderBy(m => queryParams.OrderBy);

        if (queryParams.Active)
        {
            _allItems = _allItems.Where(x => x.Estado == 1);
        }

        if ( queryParams.HasQuery() )
        {
            _allItems = _allItems
                .Where(x => x.Nombre.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(queryParams.Query.ToLowerInvariant()));
        }

        var count = _allItems.Count();

        return new ModelPageable<Tercer>(_allItems
            .Skip(queryParams.PageCount * (queryParams.Page - 1))
            .Take(queryParams.PageCount), count);
    }
```

Este es código de mi servicio que utiliza la función del repositorio

```
public ModelPageable<TercerModel> GetTercerModels(QueryParameters queryParameters)
    {
        ModelPageable<Tercer> modelPageable = GetTercers(queryParameters);
        List<Tercer> tercers = modelPageable.ModelIQueryable.ToList();
        List<TercerModel> tercerModels = new List<TercerModel>();
        foreach (Tercer tercer in tercers)
        {
            tercerModels.Add(_mapper.Map<TercerModel>(tercer));
        }
        return new ModelPageable<TercerModel>(tercerModels, modelPageable.AllItemCount);
    }

    public ModelPageable<Tercer> GetTercers(QueryParameters queryParameters)
    {
        return _tercerRepository.GetAll(queryParameters);
    }
```

en el servicio al momento de retornar los datos a una lista genérica me muestra un error

```
List<Tercer> tercers = modelPageable.ModelIQueryable.ToList();
```

este es el error

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Error: 2019-06-12 13:39:53.048269 ThreadID:8   (ERROR)   OracleRelationalCommand.Execute() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, IEnumerable`1 adrianParsedStmt, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Error: Failed executing DbCommand (72ms) [Parameters=[:p_1='?' (DbType = Int32), :p_2='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
SELECT "m"."ID", "m"."ESTADO", "m"."NOMBRE"
FROM "CROSAMPRU"."TBL_TOOLS_PET_IPS" "m"

OFFSET :p_1 ROWS FETCH NEXT :p_2 ROWS ONLY

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, IEnumerable`1 adrianParsedStmt, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Error: 2019-06-12 13:39:53.059128 ThreadID:8   (ERROR)   OracleRelationalCommand.Execute() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, IEnumerable`1 adrianParsedStmt, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Error: An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'ApiSuite.Data.NewOracleDBConnection'.
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, IEnumerable`1 adrianParsedStmt, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](IEnumerable`1 results, QueryContext queryContext, IList`1 entityTrackingInfos, IList`1 entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
```

Datos importantes a tener en cuenta.

- Funciona correctamente para SQLServer
- Uso el paquete Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore    v2.19.0 NuGet
- Uso el paquete Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core v2.19.3 NuGet
- si quito Skip y Take del repositorio funciona correctamente.

  .Skip(queryParams.PageCount * (queryParams.Page - 1))
  .Take(queryParams.PageCount)

si alguien puede ayudarme a encontrar cual es el error o en su defecto que me ayuden a darme una idea de como puedo cambiar el codigo y me de el mismo resultado sin usar .Skip y .Take estaria muy agradecido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me puse en contacto con el equipo de Oracle .NET y me respondieron lo siguiente.

**UseOracleSQLCompatibility(string version)**

This extension method specifies the database version generated SQL should be compatible with.
This method accepts either a value of "11" or "12" (default). By default, generated SQL is compatible
with database version 12 and higher. Customers using Oracle Database version 11.2 should set
UseOracleSQLCompatibility("11").

// C#

```
optionsBuilder.UseOracle("User Id=hr;Password=<password>;Data Source = inst1", b => b.UseOracleSQLCompatibility("11"));
```

Por defecto Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore viene configurado para **Oracle 12g**, pero en mi caso utilizo **Oracle 11g** y por eso se generaba el error.
Para solucionar agregué en mi **Startup.cs**

Antes

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
services.AddDbContext<NewOracleDBConnection>(options =>
              options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("NewOraConnection")));
...
}
```

Ahora

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
services.AddDbContext<NewOracleDBConnection>(options =>
              options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("NewOraConnection"), b=> b.UseOracleSQLCompatibility("11")));
...
}
```